# How can I vertically align an image and text to the middle within divs

Tags: html, css

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/S23ut/1/

I would like the image and the text to be vertically align to the middle of its container. I can't seem to get the CSS right for this. Any ideas/tricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about cross-browser compatibility, but using the CSS `display: table-XXX` might work:

```
#offer_widget .row {
    display: table-row;
}

#offer_widget .row_image {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#offer_widget .row_text {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See [this update to your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S23ut/4/).

Answer (score 0):

hey remove float and give display table properties live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/S23ut/5/

Answer (score 0):

Use below css styles in 2 nested divs:

```
display:table
display:table-cell
```

For example.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #outer{width:100px; height:60px; border:solid 1px #f00;display:table;}
        #inner{display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;font-size:16px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner">test</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```