# How to align an image and text vertically in the middle?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a DIV at the top and a few anchors. First is styled with a logo and the rest are text. The styles I've set are as follows.

```
div.nav-top {
  height: 120px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a.nav-logo {
  background: no-repeat url(Logo.png);
  background-size: 200px 40px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.nav-link {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

However, these elements are not centered **in the div**. The alignment seems to follow the image, which is at the top. The text gets in the middle **relative to the image**. It's not a bad idea **but** I need the whole system img-a-a-a-a to be centered vertically. At the moment I pad it but as soon as the height of the outer DIV changes, everything breaks.

What am I doing wrong?

(I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275285/how-can-i-vertically-align-an-image-and-text-to-the-middle-within-divs) but here they apply tables and such. Doesn't seem like the most appropriate solution. Perhaps I'm mistaken?

[image]

Comment: did you try the solution in the post you linked to or just find it? did it work? if it did work, why is it not appropriate?

Comment: @imjared Sorry for being unclear. It seemed like a very large and complicated approach for such a basic feature. I'm not saying it's wrong. Just got a feeling that centering some text in a div vertically should require something very, very basic. I try to distinguish between "getting it done" and "getting it done well".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to [this blog](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html), where the owner describes centering issues. He started 2001 **but** be aware that the last update's been made last summer, and I admire his persistence. He presents clear examples on how to center in the different versions of CSS.

In your case, I'd suggest that you use *display: flex* like so. Note that the whole centering magic's done from the containing control and imposed on the underlying children. There's actually no need to style *nav-link* at all (see remark below the example, though).

```
div.nav-top {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

a.nav-logo {
  background: no-repeat url(Logo.png);
  background-size: 200px 40px;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}

a.nav-link { }
```

That's a new thing in styling and recently implemented. The disadvantage of that is that older browsers might have problems rendering it. But the upside is that it's much more intuitive to the designers (and fetching a decent version of a browser is not a far reach, unless managed centrally by the corporate).

You might want to use *margin* for the anchor controls, as they're going to be squashed toghether. Also, the sizes and fonts will need adjusting. If you do that, you'll probably end up needing the style which I suggested wasn't needed but that's specifics only you're aware of.

```
a.nav-link {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Using **Flexbox**

```css
nav, .menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50">
  </div>
  
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Using **CSS Table**

```css
nav, .menu {
  display: table;
}

.logo, .menu {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

li {
  padding: 0 15px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50">
  </div>
  
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Sooo nice. Now, you gave me a headache because I can't decide which one to use. Is flex more modern? I know it's hard to say generally but... which is more recommended generally?   LOL   Also, a **huge +1** for the snippage.

Comment: I would use flex and i yes its more modern, but you decide http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox, http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20table

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good practice to control height with paddings instead of a fixed height and margins to center. So, keeping that in mind:

- Wrap the div with the logo and the div with the anchortags as children of a container div.
- give the purple box there (or whatever it represents the corresponding padding top and bottom to center that parent div you created inside.

  ```
  .purple{
      background:purple;
      width:400px;
      display:inline-block;
      padding: 20px 15px;
      height:auto;
  }
  ```

**EDIT**

or, if you MUST have a fixed height on the parent;

```
    .purple{
        background:purple;
        width:400px;
        display:inline-block;
        height:60px;
        padding: 0px 15px;
    }
```

See this [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yegVxW)

Comment: The purple div at the top needs to have a set height. It's going to be the menu bar. Or did I misunderstood your suggestion? I've tested the demo and as far I understand, it adapts the purple height to the contents. I wish it to be the other way around. I wish it to be fixed.

Comment: You can still manage the height with padding even if it is the menu bar. However, if you do want a fixed height, then you need margins. I'll add that approach to the demo in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your elements into a `div` and use `margin: 0, auto;` for the elements and the inner container as well.

Comment: Is it only me or is the approach a bit aged (still working, of course, and definitely backwards but still)? Would you say that the solution I suggest in my post is too narrow?

Comment: @KonradViltersten, I believe it is not important whether a solution is old or new. It is far more important to see how effective it is, how wide is the problem-space it covers, what are the side-effects and in this view it is feasible to compare the solutions. Hence, I up-voted your solution, but I would still go for the good-ol' approach without thinking twice unless I see why is it inferior to a newer approach. Backwards-compatibility, memory usage, algorithm complexity under the hoot, etc., etc.

Comment: Very wise remark, indeed. I didn't mean in any way to imply that *modern* is better (sometimes it is, of course, but more often than what we expect, it isn't). The *classic* approach has its strengths and, even if not applied, it still should be known to the decision maker. That's why I love the blog I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Not an elegant solution, but if you make a table with the text in one cell and the image in the next cell it's aligned in the middle.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use display: flex: in the div above the text then just repeat from there

```
div {

display: flex;
justify-contents: center;
align-items: center;

}
```

Comment: Please do not write pseudo code, giving an example with real code or snippet always provides a more precise and complete answer

Comment: That's not so that's three things just change the div to the class wrapped around the text or h2 or whatever tag.