# Aligning logo with nav bar

Tags: html, css

I am very new to web development and am currently trying to get a logo and list items to align with one another in the header. I would greatly appreciate your advice on what to do to fix this problem.

I have included a gist link to reference. https://gist.github.com/59c56461658d2011f8fc

Many thanks,

Josh

Comment: please create a jsfiddle/plunker

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566804/how-to-align-an-image-and-text-vertically-in-the-middle/34566964#34566964

Answer (score 1):

Your logo is overflowing because the `<img>` height is not set. If you set the height via CSS, it will be restricted to the max height of its parent (the navbar). You can do this by adding the following code to the CSS:

```
.logo img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

> JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Hybridx24/pxd1pjwz/

Comment: Does it happens the same if he set img{ max-width:100%; height:auto;} , I mean with auto height , does the image adaptives  the container height?

Comment: No, because `height: auto` is the default anyways (which is not working for him), and `max-width: 100%` means the height will still be too tall, so basically with that code it will still contain the same errors.

Comment: No , I am not talking in his case,  I am talking generally.. does height:auto filla utomatically the container's height

Comment: No - `height: auto` is not the same as `height: 100%` - `auto` ignores the parent container and calculates the height based on a ratio to the width of the same element.

Comment: Thanks mate! Really Helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You are not define logo image max height and max width. So your logo going outside of header section.

Put this css to your css file:

```css
.logo img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok All you have to do is change the nav from float: right; to float: left;

Here is a link from codepen:

`<a href="http://codepen.io/HTMLNoob/pen/xZYrpW">Example</a>`